# Combining columns from data frame

Tags: r, matrix

I want to extract certain columns from a data frame and combine them in a new one. I have the columns POS1 - POS12, in which there is a number from 1-12. This number then refers to one of the s-columns (s1-s12), in which the values are written. I want to combine these two columns into 12 columns in which the corresponding values are then placed and no longer the references to the columns s1-s12.

I used this code before and it did work, I have no idea why it does not this time. I get the following error:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': undefined columns selected

If I'm right, the error means that R can't find all the columns 1 to 12 - but I don't know why.

This is my code:

```
data_seq <- data[ which(data$MODE=='sequential'),]

data_seq = data_seq[,c(1:25, 26,29,32,35,38,41,44,47,50,53,56,59)] #remove unnecessary columns

data_test1 = data_seq[,c(1,10, 11:23, 36, 37)] #remove unnecessary columns

data_test1 = data_test1[,c(3:17, 1:2)]

data_test1$VP = as.numeric(data_test1$VP)

#grep("POS",colnames(data_seq))

data_test_pos <- data_seq[,26:37]
data_test2    <- data_seq[,11:22]

xxx<-data.frame()

for (t in 1:nrow(data_test1)) {
  xxx[t,1:12]<-as.matrix(data_test2[t,as.matrix(data_test_pos[t,])])
}

data_test_recency <- cbind(data_seq,xxx)
```

Subset from my code to maybe reproduce the problem:

```
structure(list(VP = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "2", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "3", 
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "4", 
"40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "VP"), class = "factor"), BLOCK = c("2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2"), TRIAL = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), SEX = c("1", "1", "0", 
"1", "1"), MODE = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("parallel", 
"sequential"), class = "factor"), OUTL = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), PRS = c("2", 
"12", "5", "10", "7"), DUR = c("1200", "1200", "1200", "1200", 
"1200"), L_MEAN = c("-3", "18", "13", "-24", "23"), G_MEAN = c(-3, 
11, 13, -24, 23), s1 = c("-8", "18", "6", "-26", "28"), s2 = c("-5", 
"14", "20", "-17", "21"), s3 = c("3", "22", "10", "-23", "23"
), s4 = c("-2", "14", "18", "-28", "29"), s5 = c("-5", "18", 
"8", "-20", "23"), s6 = c("-6", "25", "19", "-19", "26"), s7 = c("2", 
"17", "13", "-28", "23"), s8 = c("0", "16", "11", "-30", "19"
), s9 = c("2", "18", "9", "-26", "17"), s10 = c("-6", "22", "15", 
"-25", "25"), s11 = c("-5", "-30", "20", "-16", "18"), s12 = c("-4", 
"-26", "6", "-25", "20"), RESP = c(-5, 17, 12, -24, 22), RT = c("1871", 
"2430", "2006", "3955", "3114"), ITI = c("500", "500", "500", 
"500", "500"), POS1 = c("5", "10", "3", "8", "6"), x1 = c("-23", 
"-23", "-29", "-10", "2"), y1 = c("18", "10", "-2", "-12", "11"
), POS2 = c("2", "11", "2", "11", "1"), x2 = c("2", "-22", "-9", 
"-23", "26"), y2 = c("22", "4", "12", "-20", "23"), POS3 = c("10", 
"12", "12", "5", "5"), x3 = c("22", "20", "-14", "21", "28"), 
    y3 = c("4", "6", "-28", "14", "-30"), POS4 = c("7", "3", 
    "11", "12", "3"), x4 = c("9", "7", "-16", "9", "24"), y4 = c("-21", 
    "-25", "-17", "-27", "-19"), POS5 = c("12", "4", "6", "1", 
    "11"), x5 = c("2", "-19", "22", "-20", "12"), y5 = c("-25", 
    "-17", "13", "-28", "-4"), POS6 = c("8", "1", "5", "3", "10"
    ), x6 = c("-19", "15", "5", "3", "2"), y6 = c("26", "-7", 
    "29", "-2", "4"), POS7 = c("6", "5", "1", "6", "4"), x7 = c("11", 
    "-12", "28", "-9", "21"), y7 = c("10", "-17", "13", "13", 
    "-15"), POS8 = c("9", "8", "7", "10", "9"), x8 = c("-6", 
    "-15", "16", "-18", "4"), y8 = c("16", "-29", "-12", "-4", 
    "-23"), POS9 = c("3", "9", "10", "7", "12"), x9 = c("-9", 
    "25", "-30", "-6", "28"), y9 = c("-19", "10", "17", "22", 
    "6"), POS10 = c("4", "2", "4", "4", "7"), x10 = c("15", "-9", 
    "-7", "-1", "21"), y10 = c("30", "0", "13", "7", "1"), POS11 = c("11", 
    "6", "8", "9", "8"), x11 = c("-26", "6", "7", "-27", "-8"
    ), y11 = c("0", "-29", "-17", "-21", "26"), POS12 = c("1", 
    "7", "9", "2", "2"), x12 = c("14", "-26", "-4", "-24", "3"
    ), y12 = c("0", "28", "-24", "-24", "18"), STRT_et = c("2326169", 
    "2332032", "2338451", "2344444", "2352388"), STRT_pr0 = c("429848", 
    "435711", "442129", "448122", "456065"), STRT_pr1 = c("429848", 
    "435711", "442129", "448122", "456065")), row.names = 41:45, class = "data.frame")
```

I am thankful for any help

Comment: Please do not spam tags, the [tag:rstudio] tag is about the IDE, not one of the languages that the RStudio IDE supports (R).

Comment: I want this kind of output. This one I got from similar data, using the code provided above: 
```structure(list(V1 = c(-6L, 2L, -7L, 20L), V2 = c(30L, 2L, -10L, 
13L), V3 = c(-7L, 8L, -9L, 10L), V4 = c(-9L, 10L, -2L, 12L), 
    V5 = c(-9L, 8L, -15L, 15L), V6 = c(-5L, 10L, -12L, -28L), 
    V7 = c(-9L, -2L, -9L, 10L), V8 = c(-2L, 0L, -1L, 9L), V9 = c(-2L, 
    -3L, -13L, 16L), V10 = c(-1L, 1L, -8L, 8L), V11 = c(28L, 
    9L, -2L, -30L), V12 = c(-7L, 1L, -4L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame") ```

Comment: What can I use instead of a ```for``` loop?

Comment: I see no pattern connecting your input above with the expected output in your comment, Nori. For instance, looking at output column `V2`, the `30` appears only once in the input (in `y10[1]`), but `V2[3]` is `-10` which only appears as `x1[3]`, not a neighbor at all of `y10[1]`. (Additionally, all of the code before `data_test_pos` is not used in the rest of the question, I feel it is just a distraction.) I suggest that doing `as.matrix(...)` on row `[t,]` should be able to be done without a `for`-loop (just remove the `t`), but only if I can figure out what you are intending to do.

Comment: Like I said, the output in my comment is from slightly different data using the provided code. Sorry to be misleading - let me explain the context: I have the columns POS1 - POS12, in which there is a number from 1-12. This number then refers to one of the s-columns (s1-s12), in which the "desired" values are written. I want to combine these two columns into 12 columns in which the corresponding values are then placed and no longer the references to the columns s1-s12. Hope that explains what I actually want to do..

Comment: It's a level of indirection, it seems. Having "expected output" that is from different data lends to spinning wheels unnecessarily and often misdirected/wasted effort. Please update your expected output or your input (`data_seq`) so that they two match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick stab:

Taking the `POS*` columns,

```r
data_seq[,grepl("POS", colnames(data_seq))]
#    POS1 POS2 POS3 POS4 POS5 POS6 POS7 POS8 POS9 POS10 POS11 POS12
# 41    5    2   10    7   12    8    6    9    3     4    11     1
# 42   10   11   12    3    4    1    5    8    9     2     6     7
# 43    3    2   12   11    6    5    1    7   10     4     8     9
# 44    8   11    5   12    1    3    6   10    7     4     9     2
# 45    6    1    5    3   11   10    4    9   12     7     8     2
```

and the `s*` columns,

```r
data_seq[,grepl("^s", colnames(data_seq))]
#     s1  s2  s3  s4  s5  s6  s7  s8  s9 s10 s11 s12
# 41  -8  -5   3  -2  -5  -6   2   0   2  -6  -5  -4
# 42  18  14  22  14  18  25  17  16  18  22 -30 -26
# 43   6  20  10  18   8  19  13  11   9  15  20   6
# 44 -26 -17 -23 -28 -20 -19 -28 -30 -26 -25 -16 -25
# 45  28  21  23  29  23  26  23  19  17  25  18  20
```

you want the `POS` value (e.g., `5` is `POS1[1]`) to reflect the fifth column of the `s` columns (`s5` here) and convert the `5` into `s5[1]` of `"-5"`. The next value for `POS1` is `10`, so `s10[2]` (second row) is `22`.

Try this in one-step:

```r
POSvars <- grep("POS", colnames(data_seq), value = TRUE)
svars <- grep("^s", colnames(data_seq), value = TRUE)
stopifnot(length(POSvars) == length(svars))
POSvars
#  [1] "POS1"  "POS2"  "POS3"  "POS4"  "POS5"  "POS6"  "POS7"  "POS8"  "POS9"  "POS10" "POS11" "POS12"
svars
#  [1] "s1"  "s2"  "s3"  "s4"  "s5"  "s6"  "s7"  "s8"  "s9"  "s10" "s11" "s12"

as.data.frame(matrix(
  data_seq[,svars
    ][ cbind(rep(seq(nrow(data_seq)), times=length(svars)),
             as.integer(unlist(data_seq[,POSvars]
       )))],
  nrow=nrow(data_seq)))
#    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12
# 1  -5  -5  -6   2  -4   0  -6   2   3  -2  -5  -8
# 2  22 -30 -26  22  14  18  18  16  18  14  25  17
# 3  10  20   6  20  19   8   6  13  15  18  11   9
# 4 -30 -16 -20 -25 -26 -23 -19 -25 -28 -28 -26 -17
# 5  26  28  23  23  18  25  29  17  20  23  19  21
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it looks better than all I've come up within the last few hours. But when I run the code, I get a data frame with 5 rows and 50 columns. What I am looking for is V1-V12 for all the 7360 rows of my data frame...

Comment: I had hard-coded `5` twice, since changed. See my edits (reload if needed to find `POSvars` in the answer), it's a bit more robust to changing data size.